# how to set an azure pipeline to run ONLY 1 build at a time?

Tags: azure, devops

For the life of MS, I couldn't find a way to allow a pipeline to run a single run at a time.
Regular pipelines not releases or anything crazy.

No CI, simply to allow the pipeline to run 1 run concurrently. if another run is started it will wait for the currently running one to finish.
Something so simple. a simple queue of 1 parallel runs.

Exclusive locks aren't an option since they are at the stage level, so if my pipeline has many stages then each stage waits and they dont run together, i want the queue of runs to be at the pipeline level.

Changing to using a new Scale set of agents with just 1 agent isnt an option.
Using demands also too complex.
I just want a setting to set a pipeline max parrallel runs to 1, too simple, new runs will queue up and run in sequence.

any ideas?

wrote above.aaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can achieve this by changing parallel jobs setting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted

Organization settings > Pipelines > Parallel jobs

Comment: I assume you're thinking that you would reduce the number of parallel jobs (aka Agents) down to 1, so that only one can be run at a time.  If you want only a single pipeline of any type to run at once, then I can see this would give the desired results, I interpret the original question to be that they want "Pipeline A" to be limited to a single concurrent run -- there may be many other pipelines in the environment which don't conflict and bottlenecking everything through a single Agent probably isn't what's needed.
OP - AFAIK, I haven't seen a way to achieve this I'm afraid